# Using XPath function fn:replace from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to use XSLT to convert a simple XML schema to HTML and planned to use `fn:replace` to replace returns (`\n`) with `<p>;`. However, I can't figure out how to use this function properly.

A simplified version of the XSLT I'm using reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
      <body>
        <!-- Replace \n with <p> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="fn:replace(value, '\n', '<p>')" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the input to this XLST is e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<root>
  <value><![CDATA[
    Hello
    world!
  ]]></value>
</root>
```

The conversion fails on `fn:replace` with an NoSuchMethodException. If I change the replace statement to

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:replace('somestring', '\n', '<p>')" />
```

I get an IllegalArgumentException. How do I use `fn:replace` to achieve what I want?

I'm using [Butterfly XML Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/butterflyxml/) to test the XSLT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XPath 2.0 has a replace function that you can use with any XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML tools or Gestalt. You seem to try to use the function with an XSLT 1.0 processor, that is not going to work. In case you are restricted to an XSLT 1.0 processor you will need to implement the replacement with a named recursive template or with the help of an extension.

However note that even with XSLT 2.0 your attempt to use replace seems wrong as you will produce a text node with a 'p' tag markup while I assume you want to create a 'p' element node in the result. So even with XSLT 2.0 using analyze-string instead of replace is more likely to get you the result you want.

Comment: Thx, mentioning XSLT 2.0 pushed me in the right direction. By bumping the version attribute of <xsl:stylesheet>; to 2.0 and using <xsl:value-of select="replace(description, '\n', '&lt;p/&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />; I get the job done. Maybe analyze-string is cleaner but this gets the job done :)

Comment: Did you do anything other than just bump the version to 2.0?

Comment: can you tell me how to bumping version attribute of <xsl:stylesheet> to 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

By bumping the version attribute of `<xsl:stylesheet>` to 2.0 and using

`<xsl:value-of select="replace(description, '\n', '<p/>')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />`

I was able to make the replace work.

Comment: can you tell me how to bumping version attribute of <xsl:stylesheet> to 2.0?

Comment: @JatinPatel: `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">`