# How to use fn:replace(string,pattern,replace) in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How to use

```
      fn:replace(string,pattern,replace)
```

in XSLT

is it like < fn:replace(...)/>??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function is specified as follows:

```
fn:replace($input, $pattern, $replacement, [$flags])

$input        xs:string?  the string to change
$pattern      xs:string   regular expression to match the areas to be replaced
$replacement  xs:string   the replacement string
$flags        xs:string   flags for multiline mode, case insensitivity, etc
return value  xs:string
```

Note that `$pattern` is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and the replacement string also has some special substitution syntax.

Here are some examples:

```
# simple replacement
replace('query', 'r', 'as')               queasy

# character class
replace('query', '[ry]', 'l')             quell

# capturing group substitution
replace('abc123', '([a-z])', '$1x')       axbxcx123

# practical example
replace('2315551212',                     (231) 555-1212
    '(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})',
    '($1) $2-$3'
)
```

#### References

- [xqueryfunctions.com - Strings](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0008.html) - [`fn:replace`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_replace.html)
- [w3.org/XPath Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) - [`fn:replace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace), [Flags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - a good tutorial

Answer (score 6):

I think you do it this way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:replace(value, 'some-pattern', 'with some text')" />
```

**Edit:**

Found this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183908/using-xpath-function-fnreplace-from-xslt)