# how to use fn:replace on selected attributes?

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xpath

I have no experience with xslt but am trying to learn by tweaking some code.

In the XML I have multiple occurrences of distinct `id` and `rid` like so:

```xml
<fn id="TFN01t1"><label>*</label><p>Some text.</p></fn>
<fn id="TFN02t1"><label>**</label><p>Some text.</p></fn>
...
<p>This is a reference<xref ref-type="table-fn" rid="TFN01t1">*</xref></p>
<p>This is another reference<xref ref-type="table-fn" rid="TFN02t1">*</xref></p>
```

I need to perform the following regular expression **in ID property of fn tags** and **in RID property of any xref tag** and swap the number parts so that TFN02t1 becomes TFN1t02.

```
        "find": TFN([0-9]+)t([1-9]+)
        "replace": TFN\2t\1
```

I found [this SO answer about fn:replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183908/using-xpath-function-fnreplace-from-xslt) but dont know how to use it.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live without using regular expressions, you could also go with this simple XSLT1-compatible solution:

#### Input

```
<root>
  <fn id="TFN01t1"><label>*</label><p>Some text.</p></fn>
  <fn id="TFN02t1"><label>**</label><p>Some text.</p></fn>
  <p>This is a reference<xref ref-type="table-fn" rid="TFN01t1">*</xref></p>
  <p>This is another reference<xref ref-type="table-fn" rid="TFN02t1">*</xref></p>
</root>
```

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="fn/@id | xref[@ref-type = 'table']/@rid">
    <xsl:variable name="after-tfn" select="substring-after(., 'TFN')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="n1" select="substring-before($after-tfn, 't')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="n2" select="substring-after($after-tfn, 't')"/>

    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('TFN', $n2, 't', $n1)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <fn id="TFN1t01"><label>*</label><p>Some text.</p></fn>
  <fn id="TFN1t02"><label>**</label><p>Some text.</p></fn>
  <p>This is a reference<xref ref-type="table-fn" rid="TFN1t01">*</xref></p>
  <p>This is another reference<xref ref-type="table-fn" rid="TFN1t02">*</xref></p>
</root>
```

If you can use XSLT2 and want to use regular expressions, this stylesheet should achieve the same result:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="fn/@id | xref/@rid">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="TFN([0-9]+)t([1-9]+)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('TFN', regex-group(2), 't', regex-group(1))"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See [Regular Expression Matching in XSLT 2](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html) for more information on regular expression support in XSLT2.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do this by tweaking existing code, then it's a bit hard to help you without being able to see the existing code.

You need a template rule that matches the relevant nodes, for example

```
<xsl:template match="fn/@id | xref/@rid">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace('.', 'TFN([0-9]+)t([1-9]+)',
        'TFN$2t$1')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you need to ensure that there is somewhere in your stylesheet a call on xsl:apply-templates that selects these attribute nodes for processing, because without this your template rule will never be invoked.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. However I've just realized that my processor is version for 1 and so unfortunately I am unable to try it out... :-( I will try the version 1 of the other answer but bookmark this for I am a fan o regex.

Comment: wish I could. Thanks!